# Addition-based Captcha fails to check after one ALERT message

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, captcha

I have added a random number addition captcha to a form. The form fields are validated separately. What seems to happen is that if the captcha is blank (alert windows generated and OK button pushed) the form seems to submit anyway. Or if the captch answer is blank, the alert is generated, but clicking the Okay button submits the form.

Basically once there's a wrong captcha but all the required fields validate, the captcha doesn't really stop anything.

Random number generation is being called on the BODY, Validation is being called on the FORM line. Captcha validation is on the SUBMIT button.

I have searched for other solutions, but nothing is helping. I have also tried generating the error message like the code in the answer boxes, but that didn't help. I've simplified the page somewhat here for fewer form fields and text. Form location and email also removed.

Your help would be so appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="resource-type" content="document">
</head>
<!-- numbers generated for captcha -->
<body onLoad="randomNums();">
<!-- validation of form fields in form statement below -->
<form action="location/formemail.bml" method="get" name="contact_form" onsubmit="return Validate()">
<input type="hidden" name="my_email" value="removed" />
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Reservation Request Form" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="order" value="name,email,confirm_email,Number_Of_Adults,Number_Of_Children" />
<input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="thanks-for-your-inquiry.html" />
<input type=hidden name="print_blank_fields" value="0">
<input name="required" type="hidden" value="name,email,confirm_email,Number_Of_Adults,Number_Of_Children" />
 <center>
<table BORDER CELLSPACING=2 CELLPADDING=2 WIDTH="100%" >
 <tr>
<td>FIRST NAME and LAST NAME<span class="style2">*</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" onKeyUp="CheckForBlank('name')" onBlur="CheckForBlank('name')" title="Enter your name!" placeholder="Full Name" onClick="select()" required /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EMAIL ADDRESS<span class="style2">*</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" onKeyUp="CheckForBlank('email')" onBlur="CheckForBlank('email')" title="Enter a valid email address!" placeholder="me@example.com" onClick="select()" required="required" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Confirm EMAIL ADDRESS<span class="style2">*</span></td>
<tr>
<td>NUMBER OF ADULTS<span class="style2">*</span></td>

<td><select NAME="Number_Of_Adults" onkeyup="CheckForBlank('Number_Of_Adults')" onBlur="CheckForBlank('Number_Of_Adults')" title="Enter # Adults" 0nclick="select()" required /><option VALUE="" selected><option VALUE="1-adult">ONE</option><option VALUE="2-adults">TWO</option><option VALUE="3-adults">THREE</option><option VALUE="4-adults">FOUR</option><option VALUE="5-adults">FIVE</option><option VALUE="6-adults">SIX</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>NUMBER OF CHILDREN<span class="style2">*</span></td>
<td><select NAME="Number_Of_Children" onkeyup="CheckForBlank('Number_Of_Children')" onBlur="CheckForBlank('Number_Of_Children')" title="Enter # Children" 0nclick="select()" required /><option VALUE="NONE" selected><option VALUE="No Children">NONE</option><option VALUE="1-child">ONE</option><option VALUE="2-children">TWO</option><option VALUE="3-children">THREE</option><option VALUE="4-children">FOUR</option><option VALUE="5-children">FIVE</option><option VALUE="6-children">SIX</option></select></td>
</tr>
</table>
<center><table WIDTH="75%">
<tr>
<td>
 <fieldset>
        <label id="error"> </label>
<!-- Here is the captcha area. Onclick tests numbers. 
I believe it's here my problem occurs, but I don't know 
how to force the addNums to reloop when there's alert -->
        <div id="test-it"><strong>Add these numbers, enter in box below, and submit</strong><div id="digit1"></div><div id="plus">+</div><div id="digit2"></div></div>
<div id="buttons"><input type="text" id="answer" />
<input type="submit" value="Answer at left? Click to Submit" onClick="addNums()"/>     <input type="reset" value="Reset Form"  /></div>
<div id="status"></div>

    </fieldset>
    </td></tr>
</table>
</center>
</form>
<script>
var CheckForBlank = function (name) {
    var x = document.forms['contact_form'].elements[name].value;
    var temp = '';
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        temp = x.replace(/  /g,' ');
        x = temp;
    }
    if(temp == ' ' || temp == '  ') temp = '';
    document.forms['contact_form'].elements[name].value = temp;

    if(temp == '') {
        document.forms['contact_form'].elements[name].focus();

        document.getElementById('contact_form'+name).innerHTML = '<strong style="color:red;">You can not leave this field blank!<\/strong>';
    } else{
        document.getElementById('contact_form'+name).innerHTML = '';
    }
}

var Validate = function () {
    if( (!(/^([a-z0-9])([\w\.\-\+])+([a-z0-9])\@((\w)([\w\-]?)+\.)+([a-z]{2,4})$/i.test(document.contact_form._email.value)))  ) {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '<strong style="color:red;">Please fill in the required fields of the form! Don\'t forget to provide a valid email address! <\/strong>';
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addNums(){
var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
var digit1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML);
var digit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML);
var sum = digit1 + digit2;
if(answer == ""){
    alert("Please add the numbers");
    return false;
}else if(answer != sum){
    alert("Your answer is incorrect; try again.");
    return false;
}else{
    // all good now! //
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Correct! Thank you for validating a person is submitting the form";
    document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
}

}
function randomNums(){
var rand_num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 32) + 1;
var rand_num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML = rand_num1;
document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML = rand_num2;
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be effective, a CAPTCHA must be validated on the server side. Javascript won't cut it.

Comment: Dearest Duskwuff, unfortunately your answer is a non-answer to me because it does not begin to tell me how to fix it. I am novice enough that I do not know how to integrate the form checking with the captcha checking on a form submit (one button/click action triggering multiple actions). If you could provide some suggested edits to the code (even if it's something to the effect of "put this code in a php file and call it here like this"), that would be fantastic!

Comment: I ended up abandoning this method after finding this post. This worked flawlessly:

[link](http://blog.horizonweb.co.uk/2007/07/how-to-stop-spam-bots-with-formmail-and.html)